# Identify expression for a family of curves

Tags: geometry, polynomials

Does anyone know the expression of the family of curves shown in the attached image? I have tried the expression 
$$y = ax^3 - (a+1)x.$$ While it can approximate the curves closer to the $y = -x$ line (the dashed line) pretty well when $a \in [-1,0)$, I cannot match the curves further away from the dashed line.

[image: Family of curves]

Answer (score 0):

It's an odd function with $f(\pm 1)=\mp 1$.

It's most likely to be $$f(x)=-x^{2n-1}$$

where $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: This seems to be the correct idea, but there are issues to address. Restricting $n$ to integers leaves huge gaps in the family; on the other hand, arbitrary $n$ makes the function $x^{2n-1}$ not-necessarily-odd (consider $n=3/2$) ... not to mention that things get weird with raising negative values to non-integer powers. You really need something like $f(x) = -\operatorname{sgn}(x) |x|^p$ for arbitrary $p \geq 1$, where $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ is the ["sign function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).

Comment: @Blue, Yes. In general, $$f(x)=\sum a_{n} P_{2n-1}(x)$$ with suitable $a_{n}$ matching the boundary conditions will do.